Curve Fitting with SciPy failing to give a correct fit
I have two NumPy arrays x_data and y_data. When I try to fit my data using a second order step response model and scipy.optimize.curve_fit with this code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.array([51.5056, 51.5058, 51.5061, 51.5064, 51.5067, 51.5069, 51.5072,
       51.5075, 51.5078, 51.5081, 51.5083, 51.5086, 51.5089, 51.5092,
       51.5094, 51.5097, 51.51  , 51.5103, 51.5106, 51.5108, 51.5111,
       51.5114, 51.5117, 51.5119, 51.5122, 51.5125, 51.5128, 51.5131,
       51.5133, 51.5136, 51.5139, 51.5142, 51.5144, 51.5147, 51.515 ,
       51.5153, 51.5156, 51.5158, 51.5161, 51.5164, 51.5167, 51.5169,
       51.5172, 51.5175, 51.5178, 51.5181, 51.5183, 51.5186, 51.5189,
       51.5192, 51.5194, 51.5197, 51.52  , 51.5203, 51.5206, 51.5208,
       51.5211, 51.5214, 51.5217, 51.5219, 51.5222, 51.5225, 51.5228,
       51.5231, 51.5233, 51.5236, 51.5239, 51.5242, 51.5244, 51.5247,
       51.525 , 51.5253, 51.5256, 51.5258, 51.5261, 51.5264, 51.5267,
       51.5269, 51.5272, 51.5275, 51.5278, 51.5281, 51.5283, 51.5286,
       51.5289, 51.5292, 51.5294, 51.5297, 51.53  , 51.5303, 51.5306,
       51.5308, 51.5311, 51.5314, 51.5317, 51.5319, 51.5322, 51.5325,
       51.5328, 51.5331, 51.5333, 51.5336, 51.5339, 51.5342])

y_data = np.array([2.99 , 2.998, 3.024, 3.036, 3.038, 3.034, 3.03 , 3.025, 3.02 ,
       3.016, 3.012, 3.006, 3.003, 3.   , 2.997, 2.995, 2.993, 2.99 ,
       2.989, 2.987, 2.986, 2.985, 2.983, 2.983, 2.982, 2.98 , 2.98 ,
       2.979, 2.978, 2.978, 2.976, 2.977, 2.976, 2.975, 2.975, 2.975,
       2.975, 2.974, 2.975, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.973, 2.974, 2.973,
       2.974, 2.973, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974,
       2.973, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974,
       2.975, 2.974, 2.975, 2.975, 2.976, 2.976, 2.976, 2.976, 2.975,
       2.976, 2.976, 2.977, 2.977, 2.976, 2.977, 2.977, 2.977, 2.977,
       2.978, 2.978, 2.978, 2.979, 2.978, 2.978, 2.979, 2.979, 2.979,
       2.979, 2.979, 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.981, 2.981,
       2.981, 2.981, 2.982, 2.981, 2.982])

# Second order function definition
def second_order_step_response(t, K, zeta, omega_n):
    omega_d = omega_n * np.sqrt(1 - zeta**2)
    phi = np.arccos(zeta)
    return K * (1 - (1 / np.sqrt(1 - zeta**2)) * np.exp(-zeta * omega_n * t) * np.sin(omega_d * t + phi))

# Initial Guess of parameters 
K_guess = y_data.max() - y_data.min()
zeta_guess = 0.5  # Typically between 0 and 1 for underdamped systems
omega_n_guess = 2 * np.pi / (x_data[1] - x_data[0])  # A rough estimate based on data sampling rate

# Fit the model with increased maxfev and parameter bounds
params, covariance = curve_fit(
    second_order_step_response, x_data, y_data,
    p0=[K_guess, zeta_guess, omega_n_guess],
    maxfev=5000,  # Increase max function evaluations
    bounds=([0, 0, 0], [np.inf, 1, np.inf])  # Bounds for K, zeta, and omega_n
)
K_fitted, zeta_fitted, omega_n_fitted = params

# Generate data for the fitted model
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 300)  # More points for a smoother line
y_fit = second_order_step_response(x_fit, K_fitted, zeta_fitted, omega_n_fitted)

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, color='red', label='Original Data')  # Original data
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, 'blue', label='Fitted Model')  # Fitted model
plt.title('Fitting Second Order System Step Response to Data')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Display fitted parameters
print(f"Fitted Parameters: Gain (K) = {K_fitted}, Damping Ratio (zeta) = {zeta_fitted}, Natural Frequency (omega_n) = {omega_n_fitted}")


This is the equation I am using to fit the data

I get the following fit. The K_fitted(gain) and zeta_fitted(dampening coefficient) are within realistic values but omega_n_fitted is way to large.

What is the problem?
Edit1: Adding image over underdamped and overdamped systems for context. I am fitting the underdamped system


Your initial guess for the parameters is too far away from the correct solution and the optimisation just goes haywire. It ought to warn you that the fit is poor/failed. Numerical stability isn't helped by having an additive constant of 51.5 on the time axis either.  Guess parameters from FWHM of the peak and it might stand a chance.

Where is your equation from? Why do you define a phi but not use it?

@jared I was rewriting the equation and forgot to erase phi. I edited the code to include phi. I added a picture describing the equation

I can get a fit (using a modified equation), but it's not so great because of that curved tail.

Your data looks like the frequency is changing in time, while your model has constant frequency.

Your equation is for an underdamped system, but your data is over-damped (no real oscillation). Try fitting the overdamped equation (deficit of two decaying exponentials) instead.

@lastchance I am fitting an underdamped system. The data resembles an underdamped system. I added an image of different damping degrees under edit 1. Do you think the data does not suggest an underdamped system?

The precise form of the picture depends on the initial boundary conditions (displacement and velocity) - the overdamped case may well pass through the equilibrium line once before slowly asymptoting back toward it. An underdamped system has a single frequency (omega_d in your formula) and an amplitude decaying exponentially. Your data does not have an identifiable frequency.

I find it unlikely that this would be able to fit without providing for a t0 degree of freedom, given your x_data

COMMENT :
The model equation appears not well compatible with the data. The fitting is far to be correct.
A different model equation is considered below. The variable t is repaced by a variable x=ln(t-t0). Of course this isn't significant on physical viewpoint. This is purely mathematical.


That is an ingenious empirical fit to the data. My fit preferred 51.5056 and using the classical second order damped model refused to fit the tail correctly.

@JJAcquelin. Wow, what a wizard. The model that I was using indeed appears to not be appropriate for the data. Your model is able to capture both of the tail end and the remain portion of the data. I will try to make physical sense why the equations work and what they describe in this system. Thank you!

I doubt that the empirical model has a physical sense. Probably one could find other empirical models fitting the data as well without beeing able to say which one is better on physical viewpoint. I would be more confident in searching to built a model from the study of the phenomenon involved. Good luck !

A fairly-standard physical model for this is given below.
For the data as is (but see the bottom of this post) the best fit seems to come with critically damped (damping ratio zeta=1). Attempted
best fits with either under-damped or over-damped solutions give zeta-->1, so you might as well go directly with critically-damped.
Displacement-from-equilibrium solutions for a linear-damping model (mechanical or electrical) for reference. Free constants A, B come from boundary conditions (i.e., the point where the forcing is removed).

Both over- and critically-damped give equilibrium y value of 3.01 and omega=76.47. These solutions look nearly indistinguishable on a graph.
The underdamped solution can get the initial "bump", but can't track the tail. The critically-damped and overdamped solutions get the bulk of the data, but not the start (which may still include some of the initial forcing).
I've subtracted the initial time t0 from the x data. There is no real need to fit this: if you left it in as a free parameter then it would simply get absorbed into the constants multiplying the exponential terms or change the phase in the sine term.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.array([51.5056, 51.5058, 51.5061, 51.5064, 51.5067, 51.5069, 51.5072,
       51.5075, 51.5078, 51.5081, 51.5083, 51.5086, 51.5089, 51.5092,
       51.5094, 51.5097, 51.51  , 51.5103, 51.5106, 51.5108, 51.5111,
       51.5114, 51.5117, 51.5119, 51.5122, 51.5125, 51.5128, 51.5131,
       51.5133, 51.5136, 51.5139, 51.5142, 51.5144, 51.5147, 51.515 ,
       51.5153, 51.5156, 51.5158, 51.5161, 51.5164, 51.5167, 51.5169,
       51.5172, 51.5175, 51.5178, 51.5181, 51.5183, 51.5186, 51.5189,
       51.5192, 51.5194, 51.5197, 51.52  , 51.5203, 51.5206, 51.5208,
       51.5211, 51.5214, 51.5217, 51.5219, 51.5222, 51.5225, 51.5228,
       51.5231, 51.5233, 51.5236, 51.5239, 51.5242, 51.5244, 51.5247,
       51.525 , 51.5253, 51.5256, 51.5258, 51.5261, 51.5264, 51.5267,
       51.5269, 51.5272, 51.5275, 51.5278, 51.5281, 51.5283, 51.5286,
       51.5289, 51.5292, 51.5294, 51.5297, 51.53  , 51.5303, 51.5306,
       51.5308, 51.5311, 51.5314, 51.5317, 51.5319, 51.5322, 51.5325,
       51.5328, 51.5331, 51.5333, 51.5336, 51.5339, 51.5342])

y_data = np.array([2.99 , 2.998, 3.024, 3.036, 3.038, 3.034, 3.03 , 3.025, 3.02 ,
       3.016, 3.012, 3.006, 3.003, 3.   , 2.997, 2.995, 2.993, 2.99 ,
       2.989, 2.987, 2.986, 2.985, 2.983, 2.983, 2.982, 2.98 , 2.98 ,
       2.979, 2.978, 2.978, 2.976, 2.977, 2.976, 2.975, 2.975, 2.975,
       2.975, 2.974, 2.975, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.973, 2.974, 2.973,
       2.974, 2.973, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974,
       2.973, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974, 2.974,
       2.975, 2.974, 2.975, 2.975, 2.976, 2.976, 2.976, 2.976, 2.975,
       2.976, 2.976, 2.977, 2.977, 2.976, 2.977, 2.977, 2.977, 2.977,
       2.978, 2.978, 2.978, 2.979, 2.978, 2.978, 2.979, 2.979, 2.979,
       2.979, 2.979, 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.98 , 2.981, 2.981,
       2.981, 2.981, 2.982, 2.981, 2.982])

x_data = x_data - x_data[0]


# Second order function definition
def underDamped(t, y0, A, B, omega, zeta ):
    omega_d = omega * np.sqrt( 1 - zeta ** 2 )
    return y0 + A * np.exp( -zeta * omega * t ) * np.sin( omega_d * t + B )
under0 = [ 3, 0.1, 0.0, 50.0, 0.1 ]
punder, cv = curve_fit( underDamped, x_data, y_data, p0=under0, bounds=([0,-np.inf,-np.inf,0.0,0.0],[10,np.inf,np.inf,np.inf,1.0]), maxfev=10000 )

def overDamped(t, y0, A, B, omega, zeta ):
    lambda1 = omega * ( zeta - np.sqrt( zeta ** 2 - 1 ) )
    lambda2 = omega * ( zeta + np.sqrt( zeta ** 2 - 1 ) )
    return y0 + A * np.exp( -lambda1 * t ) + B * np.exp( -lambda2 * t )
over0 = [ 3, 0.1, 0.1, 50.0, 2.0 ]
pover, cv = curve_fit( overDamped, x_data, y_data, p0=over0, maxfev=10000 )

def criticallyDamped(t, y0, A, B, omega ):
    return y0 + ( A + B * t ) * np.exp( -omega * t )
crit0 = [ 3, 0.1, 0.1, 50.0 ]
pcrit, cv = curve_fit( criticallyDamped, x_data, y_data, p0=crit0, maxfev=10000 )

# Generate data for the fitted model
x_fit = np.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 300)  # More points for a smoother line
u_fit = underDamped     ( x_fit, *punder )
o_fit = overDamped      ( x_fit, *pover  )
c_fit = criticallyDamped( x_fit, *pcrit  )

# Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, color='black', label='Original Data')
plt.plot(x_fit, u_fit, 'red',   label='Underdamped')
plt.plot(x_fit, o_fit, 'blue' , label='Overdamped')
plt.plot(x_fit, c_fit, 'green', label='Critically damped')
plt.title('Fitting Second Order System Step Response to Data')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Display fitted parameters
print( "Underdamped:       y0, A, B, omega, zeta = ", *punder )
print( "Overdamped:        y0, A, B, omega, zeta = ", *pover  )
print( "Critically-damped: y0, A, B, omega = "      , *pcrit  )

Output:
Underdamped:       y0, A, B, omega, zeta =  2.976449192328566 -45.10851382377807 -3.1413665103191675 815.1575670585344 0.9999946970217488
Overdamped:        y0, A, B, omega, zeta =  3.011323385679147 -4.798576387293144 4.8163356019586825 76.46587506775039 1.000079837533067
Critically-damped: y0, A, B, omega =  3.011320122667347 0.017762157049911867 -9.290153164255033 76.47022695793991


EDIT: Following Martin Brown's comment I also tried removing the first 4 points. Critically-damped (damping ratio zeta=1) then fits the case very well. There are revised values of the equilibrium position (y0=2.982) and natural circular frequency (omega=172.686).
Critically-damped: y0, A, B, omega =  2.982416646620049 0.055681833492928545 -10.697532138927013 172.6861383346045



I have a suspicion that the first 4 points of these data are during the application of some external forces and so do not belong to the solution. Pretending that it is critically damped allows a fitting a slightly steeper rise time. I get a similar fit and whatever I do I cannot reproduce the linearly rising baseline on the exit wings. There is some detail that the OP hasn't told us about his experiment.  Fitting L2 vs L1 norms doesn't help either (the latter moves the residuals mostly onto the baseline).

"I have a suspicion that the first 4 points of these data are during the application of some external forces" - yes, I agree with that. I still think the subsequent behaviour (in the absence of a definite oscillation frequency) implies critically damped or overdamped. If you remove the first 4 points then critically-damped fits the behaviour very well.

@MartinBrown. This data is an excerpt of a transient voltage response. Simply stated, we go from low current to high current and measure the voltage vs time. You are correct. The external force (high current) was applied about 1 second before the first 4 datapoints. All the data shown here is at that higher current. The voltage vs time data that we get is the system response

@impedance_gatto, what is in the electric circuit? If you know the resistance, capacitance and inductance you could work out the natural frequency and damping ratio. As it stands, it looks like someone has set it up perfectly to be critically damped (which would usually be a good result).

That later fit looks altogether much more convincing. Is the critical damping by good luck or by design? You could always load it up with some extra capacitance or inductance as a final test.

@lastchance This is a fuel cell with many individual parts and layers. We do not know the individual resistances or values. All we have is the voltage response over time. I thought this model might do a goodfit for this but it looks to be deficient. I have been able to fit the peak section well but at the cost of poor fitting of the remaining data. And I have also been able to fit the later half of the data but giving a poor fit for the peak section. It seems that this model is not appropriate to fit both of these. JJaquelin has a more general approach that may be best suited for this data

@Martin Brown, I suspect that the critical damping is by design: it is the condition with fastest return to equilibrium. That is desirable in both mechanical and electrical systems.
